# Can I Upsert based on a condition?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

So, I am currently using this AMPScript to upsert:

```
%%[
upsertDE("MyDE",1,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"EmailSend_Status",0,"EmailSend_StatusChangeDate", Now())
]%%
```

In my DE, EmailAddress is not a primary key because one email can be in multiple rows in MyDE.

My current AMPScript is updating ALL rows for the email address.

Is there any way I can add condition to UPSERT so that update is done only for rows that I want?

Like this...

```
%%[
upsertDE("MyDE",1,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"EmailSend_Status",0,"EmailSend_StatusChangeDate", Now() WHERE EmailSend_Status is FALSE)
]%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use an [IF THEN](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_langauge_elements/) statement to only run the upsert when the condition is false.

```
%%[

    SET @EmailSend_Status = AttributeValue("EmailSend_Status")

    IF @EmailSend_Status == false THEN

upsertDE("MyDE",1,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"EmailSend_Status",0,"EmailSend_StatusChangeDate", Now())

    ELSE

      /* Default action */

    ENDIF

]%%
```

or if you do not want to have an else action, you can just leave out the else statement. This way the content will only be run if the criteria is met.

```
%%[

    SET @EmailSend_Status = AttributeValue("EmailSend_Status")

    IF @EmailSend_Status == false THEN

    upsertDE("MyDE",1,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"EmailSend_Status",0,"EmailSend_StatusChangeDate", Now())

    ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: In ELSE condition is there any way to add "do nothing"? Since I only have IF condition in my case there is no else. It's basically IF condition is true then do something else do nothing.

Comment: Yes, you can just exclude the else. Will add this option into my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One other related question. Right now I have this AMPScript which displays the First Name of the email recipient. `%%[
var @fname
set @fname = [FirstName]
]%%

Dear %%[IF not empty(@fname) THEN]%%%%=v(@fname)=%%%%[ELSE]%%Member%%[ENDIF]%%`         Since my data extension includes a primary key which is not email address. One email can be in multiple rowswith different name. In my case, I want ampscript to display first name from the record where `@EmailSend_Status == false`. How can I do that?

Comment: @kumi - Please post this as a new question and I will gladly take a look at it.  We want others to be able to search and find the solutions shared hear, which unfortunately is more difficult if they are in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes agree that it should be in a separate topic. here - [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186616/can-i-add-condition-to-ampscript)